# View controller only loading images correctly the first time

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a view controller to dynamically show buttons and buttons with images. I re-use this view controller at different levels in my app. The first time it opens it's showing the images correctly. When I go one step back and re-open the same view it shows the last image loaded on all buttons.

Below are screen shots showing it working correctly the first time yet not the second time. What am I doing wrong?

Correct:

[image: Correct]

Showing all the same image:

[image: Showing all the same image]

Relevant Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        AddImages()
        ListFolders()
}



func ListFolders(){
    do {
        let filemgr = FileManager.default
        let filelist = try filemgr.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: BaseFolder + "/Edussentials/Home/" + MyFolder)

        for file in filelist {
            if (MyFunctions().mid(file,0,4) == "BUT_") || (MyFunctions().mid(file,0,4) == "IBT_") {
                IncreaseMyArrays()
                MyButton_Name[ButtonCount] = MyFunctions().mid(file, 4, 50)
                MyButton_Type[ButtonCount] = MyFunctions().mid(file, 0, 4)
                ReadButtons(ButtonFolder: BaseFolder + "/Edussentials/Home/" + MyFolder + "/" + file)
                ButtonCount += 1
            }
        }
        CreateIButtons()
        CreateButtons()

    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}


func CreateIButtons(){

    var i: Int = 0
    repeat {
        if (MyButton_Type[i] == "IBT_"){
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: Int(MyDisplayWidth / 100 * Float(MyButton_xPos[i])), y: Int(MyDisplayHeight / 100 * Float(MyButton_yPos[i] + MySetFromTop)), width: Int(MyDisplayWidth / 100 * Float(MyButton_Width[i])), height: Int(MyDisplayHeight / 100 * Float(MyButton_Height[i]))))
            let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: BaseFolder + "/Edussentials/Home/" + MyFolder + "/IBT_" + MyButton_Name[i] + "/MyImage.gif")
            let MyImage = UIImage(named: imageURL.path)!
            button.setImage(MyImage, for: UIControlState.normal)
            button.tag = i
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.view.addSubview(button)
        }
        i += 1
    } while i < ButtonCount
}
```

Comment: Where are you using this code in your viewcontroller?

Comment: in the view controller in a function called from viewDidLoad

Comment: please add this statement `print(imageURL)`  before this line `let MyImage = UIImage(named: imageURL.path)!` and see does it print different urls when you again open the view?

Comment: I'm having the same problem for an image I use as background. Code is inside the same view controller.//Set the background
        let imagebg = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: Int(MyDisplayWidth / 100 * Float(0)), y: Int(MyDisplayHeight / 100 * Float(MySetFromTop)), width: Int(MyDisplayWidth / 100 * Float(100)), height: Int(MyDisplayHeight / 100 * Float(100))))
        let imageURLbg = URL(fileURLWithPath: BaseFolder + "/Edussentials/Home/" + MyFolder + "/background.jpg")
        imagebg.image = UIImage(named: imageURLbg.path)
        self.view.addSubview(imagebg)

Comment: I did try that and it does use the different URLs

Comment: ok can you please show the complete `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: When I go from this view controller to an other view controller and then go back the problem also is the same.

Comment: In this case I think you should write the above code inside the `viewWillAppear` method instead of `viewDidLoad` because `viewDidLoad` is called once when you initially show the view whereas `viewWillAppear` method will also be called when you go to another viewcontroller and then come back

Comment: @Edussentials Please do not post code in comments. [Edit] your question as needed with all **relevant** details.

Comment: I just tried to call my funcs from viewWillAppear but I have the same problem

Comment: Ok you need to some more debugging, please add this statement `print(myImage)` after this statement `let MyImage = UIImage(named: imageURL.path)!` and see what does it print, if your urls are different then these images should also be different

Comment: The result of the print(MyImage) as below
This is the output of the first load:

<UIImage: 0x6040000bfa40>, {475, 402}
<UIImage: 0x6040002a0ea0>, {472, 402}
<UIImage: 0x6040002a1020>, {475, 405}
<UIImage: 0x6040002a1200>, {502, 822}
<UIImage: 0x6040002a13e0>, {472, 402}

This when loading the same again.

<UIImage: 0x6040002a14a0>, {472, 402}
<UIImage: 0x6040002a15c0>, {472, 402}
<UIImage: 0x6040002a3840>, {472, 402}
<UIImage: 0x6040002a3960>, {472, 402}
<UIImage: 0x6040002a3b40>, {472, 402}

Comment: I also tested by setting the button’s background picture.
This will give the same picture (last one of the 5) everywhere already after the first load.

Comment: I solved the problem. In UIImage I used named: but I needed to use contentsOfFile: together with the full path of the location of the image.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you are reusing that view to multiple times into your app. Here you had put `if` for customising your view, but forgot to implement `else` to make that view into it's original state.

Put your code to make view to it default state using `else` after every `if`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of pointing to the image is using UIImage(contentsOfFile: "MyFullPath") and not UIImage(named: "MyFullPath")
The problem was that all my images have the same name but are located in different directories. For some reason UIImage dit get the correct image the first time the view was called. However the second time the view was called it pointed to the last found directory hence showing the same image on every button.

```
button.setImage(UIImage(contentsOfFile: BaseFolder + "/Edussentials/Home/" + MyFolder + "/IBT_" + MyButton_Name[i] + "/MyImage.gif"), for: UIControlState.normal)
```